# How should I ask a question arising from the answer to another question?

Tags: support

I enjoyed the question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815586/entity-framework-using-transactions-or-savechangesfalse-and-acceptallchanges) but found it doesn't work with a newer version of Entity Framework (Code First).  Should I ask a new question and put a link to the old one, or should I add comments to the old question?

Comment: both would be fine ... first comment and if not get replay ask another  and also tell about that so user wont close it as dup of that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it makes sense to document this as a separate question. This way people can find the exact solution to the problem based on what version they are using, without having to look through comments or trying something that won't work.

I would link to the original question and explain why it doesn't work with the new version and also put a comment in the original q/a to the new question.

Comment: Thank you @Oleksi, I tried adding a comment yesterday with no response so far. I have posted the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944802/doing-transactions-with-entity-framework-code-first)

Comment: And linked the comment on the original question to the new question